# Changes to VB.NET namespace behavior in .NET vs .NET Framework

Tags: vb.net

I'm upgrading VB.NET projects from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 6 and I'm very confused by changes to namespace behavior.

I have one project (I'll call it "project A") configured with a root namespace of "Abc.Library.Database" and a class defined like so:

```
Public Class TypeX

End Class
```

The definition of TypeX is not explicitly contained with a namespace so its namespace should match the root namespace of the project (i.e. "Abc.Library.Database").

I have a project reference setup from another project (project B) to project A.  Project B has a root namespace of "Abc.Library".  In project B I'm trying to declare a variable of type TypeX like so:

```
Namespace Abc.Library.Logging

   Public Class Logger

      Public Sub DoSomething()
         Dim x As Abc.Library.Database.TypeX
      End Sub

   End Class

End Namespace
```

That worked fine in .NET Framework 4.8, but in .NET 6 that results in a compile error and the suggestion is to change the definition to:

```
Dim x As Abc.Library.Abc.Library.Database.TypeX
```

I tried wrapping the definition of TypeX in an explicit namespace as shown below but it made no difference:

```
Namespace Abc.Library.Database

   Public Class TypeX

   End Class

End Namespace
```

I tried searching for an explanation to why and how the behavior of VB.NET namespaces was changed from .NET Framework to .NET 6 (and presumably .NET 5 and .NET Core) but haven't had any luck.

I also found that auto-generated code (e.g. DataSet.Designer.vb) is now wrapping the generated class definition in a namespace that matches the root namespace of the project (which would be fine) but then appends the name of any folders.  Searching leads me to believe that there is no way to prevent that from happening.

I'm just trying to figure out how to define my types such that I can keep the declarations of those types the same and avoid the redundant namespace prefixes.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure on the explanation of the changes, but how about adding 'Imports Abc.Library.Database' to your logger class and then 'Dim x As TypeX' ?

Comment: Sure enough, that works.  Unfortunately that means that I'm going to have to add import statements to thousands of files and change even more declarations to not explicitly specify the namespace.  Your suggestion also led me to discover that I can prepend "Global." to the declaration (e.g. "Dim x As Global.Abc.Library.Database") and that works without the import statement, but either way I'm in for a lot of changes.  I appreciate your suggestion, Andrew, thanks for your help.

Comment: Before you change too much, wait and see if someone else has a better answer. Possibly there is some other trick to it that saves you having to change so much code. How are you actually upgrading though? Are you creating a .net6 project and copy the class files over into it? (Just for interest sake)

Comment: This works without the imports statement: 'Dim x As Database.TypeX'

Comment: I'm branching each project in Azure DevOps and then using the .NET Upgrade Assistant.  Good find about using just "Database.TypeX".  It seems like if you specify a root namespace for the project, the namespaces defined in code are being appended to the root namespace.  That's different from .NET Framework, where the namespace definition in code would completely override whatever the project's root namespace was.  Although that alone doesn't really explain my original problem where I wasn't even wrapping the TypeX definition in a namespace.

Comment: FYI - I decided to report this issue in the Visual Studio developer community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VB-projects-for-NET-6-are-not-handling-/10033929

Comment: Cool, thanks for the update. Hopefully you get a good answer soon.